# How to update a column of a table with value of another colum, in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to update a column of a table with value of another column. The SQL looks like this.

```
UPDATE table_name set col1 = col2 WHERE created_at < '2013-05-01' ;
```

Is there a way of doing this in rails without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont care abt validations or callbacks, this will do

```
Model.update_all("col1 = col2", ["created_at < ?", '2013-05-01'])
```